# Spring Integration JMS Consumers not consuming all messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-jms

## Setup

I have Spring Boot application called the **Dispatcher**. It runs on 1 Machine and has an embedded ActiveMQ Broker:

```
  @Bean
  public BrokerService broker(ActiveMQProperties properties) throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setPersistent(false);
    broker.addConnector(properties.getBrokerUrl());
    return broker;
  }
```

which writes tasks to a JMS queue:

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows
      .from(taskQueue())
      .bridge(Bridges.blockingPoller(outboundTaskScheduler()))
      .transform(outboundTransformer)
      .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
        .extractPayload(false)
        .destination(JmsQueueNames.STANDARD_TASKS))
      .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public QueueChannel standardTaskQueue() {
    return MessageChannels.priority()
      .comparator(TASK_PRIO_COMPARATOR)
      .get();
  }

  // 2 more queues with different names but same config
```

The **Worker** Application runs on 10 Machines with 20 cores each and is configured like this:

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow standardTaskInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    int maxWorkers = 20;
    return IntegrationFlows
      .from(Jms.channel(connectionFactory)
        .sessionTransacted(true)
        .concurrentConsumers(maxWorkers)
        .taskExecutor(
          Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxWorkers, new CustomizableThreadFactory("standard-"))
        )
        .destination(JmsQueueNames.STANDARD_TASKS))
      .channel(ChannelNames.TASKS_INBOUND)
      .get();
  }

  // 2 more inbound queues with different names but same config
```

This is repeated for a 2nd queue, plus 1 special case. So there is **a total of 401 consumers**.

## Observation

Using JConsole, I can see that there are tasks in the ActiveMQ queue:

[TODO insert screenshot]

As expected, on any Worker machine, there are 20 consumer threads:

[TODO insert screenshot]

But most if not all of them are *idle* even though there are still messages in the queue. Using our monitoring tool, I see that about 50 to 400 tasks are being processed at any given time, when the expectation is a constant 400.

I also observed that Spring creates `AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer` for each consumer, which seem to result in 1 JMS connection being opened per application per queue per second (33 connections per second).

## Investigation

So I found [I do not receive messages in my second consumer](https://activemq.apache.org/i-do-not-receive-messages-in-my-second-consumer) which hints at `prefetch` being the culprit. This sounded plausible, so I configured `tcp://dispatcher:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1` on each worker. Then, however, only about 25 tasks were being processed at any point which made no sense to me at all.

## Question

I don't seem to understand what's going on and since I'm running out of time to investigate, I was hoping that anyone could point me in the right direction. Which factors could be the reason? The number of consumers/connections? The prefetch? Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be actually caused by the prefetch policy. The correct configuration in my case was to use `tcp://dispatcher:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0`

In my earlier (failed) test I used `jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1` but in hindsight I'm not sure whether I configured it at the correct place.